# Sentry doesn't provide operating system on events

Tags: flutter, sentry

We are using sentry on our flutter app which is quite good tool.

But it doesn't show iOS operating system on events like this:

[image: Event on Sentry for iOS]

But it shows on Android on the same event

[image: Event on Sentry for Android]

The way I am initializing sentry is like this

```
await SentryFlutter.init(
        (options) {
          options.dsn = SecretUtils.instance.get(key);
          options.environment = environment;
        },
        appRunner: appRunner,
      );
```

appRunner simply runs my application. Is there any way of getting iOS tag on events

Edit:
Issiu fixed. More info -> https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dart/pull/958

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue in the Sentry SDK for flutter, I've created an issue: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dart/issues/942

In the meantime, the workaround could be setting the operating system manually in the current scope's context: https://pub.dev/documentation/sentry/latest/sentry_io/Contexts/operatingSystem.html

Something like this could work (not tested):

```dart
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

if (Platform.isIOS) {
  Sentry.configureScope((scope) => scope.setContexts('os', {
    'name': Platform.operatingSystem
  }));
}
```